# Can I install the disc-based DLC for my digital copy of Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, xbox-360

I have a digital copy of Spirit on my Xbox 360 and I'm thinking about getting a disc copy that has the dlc's to put on my Xbox. Is that possible?

Comment: What is your downloaded copy of Skyrim?

Comment: The normal. Nothing on it just the normal downloaded copy of skyrim.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, The Elder Scrolls V Skyrim: Legendary Edition is a 2-disk edition of the game, which includes all dlc packs.

The first disk contains the game as normal. The second disk contains the dlc packs, which you must install to your consoles HDD to use. You will need sufficient space on your HDD to install the content as it won't run from disk.